# how can I use both of them correctly (dismal vs hapless)

Tags: usage

- dismal is sad and without hope
- hapless is out of luck

how can I use both of them correctly ?

Comment: You probably don't really want to *ever* use ***hapless***. It's hopelessly (not ***dismally***) "dated, poetic".

Comment: I don't understand hapless is not a English word or It's old(outdated) and it's replaced

Comment: It's not like there's a committee somewhere deciding to retire old words and replace them with new ones (no-one would take any notice of them even if they did). Most native speakers would *recognise* the word, but you'd almost never hear it in a conversational context today unless the speaker was deliberately mimicking a poetic and/or dated style.

Comment: Someone will probably give more background in a proper answer, but I'll just point out that ***dismal*** is also slightly "poetic" compared to more common words like ***sad, unhappy***. Consequently, people will tend to suppose that if you *do* choose to use it you're trying to "emphasis" how gloomy/cheerless something is. Note that it's not idiomatic to say *I'm dismal* to mean *I'm very sad* - it's more likely to be used in contexts such as *This is a dismal place* (the place itself isn't feeling miserable; it just has that effect on the speaker).

Comment: Did you check a dictionary and example questions? [*dismal*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dismal) and [*hapless*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hapless)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  "hapless" might be old and forgotten, but I don't think it's [quite dead yet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=hapless&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=3).  I agree it's too melodramatic for everyday use, though.

Comment: I would say **dismal** conveys more than "sad and without hope" such as a weather forecast, and **hapless** implies *continually* unlucky or even inexpert such as in "a hapless fool".

Comment: @FumbleFingers but there *is* a committee out there reviewing the [next edition of a dictionary](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/june-2017-update/).

Comment: @FumbleFingers This will seem needlessly contrarian of me, but I wouldn't advise someone never to use _hapless_. It's a fine word, it might even be the _best_ word in some contexts, and if it regains currency, I say all the better. Let's have more words, not fewer. Let's have some churn. I hear my offspring say that so-and-so "vexes" them. Twenty years ago, mightn't someone have said "Oh, don't use that, it's archaic?"

Comment: @P.E.Dant well said, the English language has a rich vocabulary full of nuances, with a danger of being dumbed down to grunts by... I won't write a rant.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: As a Lit Studies graduate myself, I would certainly never advise a competent wordsmith to avoid words like ***hapless***. But people at that level wouldn't be asking *how* to use such words here on ELL - they'd be people who've had sufficient exposure to English (in particular, *literary* use of English) that they wouldn't need to ask things like that here. At most I might flag up [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+hapless+pair&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20hapless%20pair%3B%2Cc0) showing a decline.

Comment: when we study  for tests like ITELS and TOEFL , we learn a bunch of words that looked close to each other in meaning and weird to use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was surprised at how many _haplesses_ I found in the wild. It's not ready for the dustbin yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hapless*** means "without hap", and "hap" came to English from the same folk who brought the *[Danegeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danegeld)* to England and *[lutefisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lutefisk)* to Minnesota: the Scandinavians. It's a very old word, and means "good fortune", and at its root, *chance* or *eventuality*. It's at the root of countless other words like *happy*, *mishap*, and *happen,* (which may be a vestige of the inflected verb *hap*). "Hapless" in English conjures a vision of **[Joe Btfsplk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Btfsplk)**:
[image]
It's much unluckier than just unlucky. It's downright dismal.

The adjective ***Dismal*** was originally a noun, and comes to English from the Latin *dies mali* ("evil days") by way of the Old French  *dis mal*. Until the 1400's, there were still noted on many calendars some days which were deemed unlucky. The OED tells us:

> The *dies mali* were Jan. 1, 25; Feb. 4, 26; March 1, 28; April 10, 20; May 3, 25; June 10, 16; July 13, 22; Aug. 1, 30; Sept. 3, 21; Oct. 3, 22; Nov. 5, 28; Dec. 7, 22. They are said to have been called ‘Egyptian days’ because first discovered or computed by Egyptian astrologers; though some mediæval writers connected them with the plagues of ancient Egypt...

By extension the noun "dismal" was used to describe anyone or anything that smacked of evil, the Devil, death, gloom, or ill fortune. By 1621, it was a familiar adjective, and Robert Burton writes in the abstract to his *[Anatomy of Melancholy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Anatomy_of_Melancholy)*:

> *Doleful outcries, and fearful sights,
>
>   My sad and dismal soul affrights*

It was still used attributively and as a noun in the 18th century; President John Adams of the United States wrote to his wife in 1774:

> *"Their mutual reproaches, their declamations..their triumphs and defiances, their dismals and prophecies, are all delusion."*

*Dismal* is still in use today, both as an adjective that means *"boding or bringing misfortune and disaster; unlucky, sinister, malign, fatal"* <sup>†</sup> and as *"A local name of dreary tracts of swampy land on the eastern sea-board of the United States, esp. in North Carolina."* <sup>‡</sup>:

[image]
<sup>***A Dismal in North Carolina***</sup>

In commentary to your question, you mention that in studying for your ITELS and TOEFL tests, you learned a "*bunch of words that looked close to each other in meaning and weird to use."* It's certainly true that *hapless* and *dismal* could sound weird in the wrong context; yet consider that a "weird" word may be just the right choice. *Hapless* is very widely used today to describe the unfortunate:

> *"The hapless Sean Spicer is only the latest to get the message
> that his services were no longer required"* *

[image]
<sup>(*The New Yorker*, Jul 4, 2017)</sup>

The best advice to a student of English is to cherish the depth and richness of our polyglot tongue, to savor its oddities, to read everything you can get your hands on, and to listen to conversation to understand when a choice of words is dismal, or a speaker hapless. Someday, you may well overhear teenagers leaving a concert and saying:

> ***"Dude, that set was totally dismal."
>
>   "Ya think? He's like hapless!"***

<sup>†</sup> <sup>‡</sup><sub>Oxford English Dictionary</sub>

* <sub>[*The Week*, June 25, 2017](http://theweek.com/articles/714005/how-keep-job-trump-white-house)</sub>